# chartJS, how to disable user from clicking on legend names and changing the graph?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

This is a react project. I'm running the latest version of all software. I am trying to create a pie chart but when the legend names are clicked, it changes the graph. So far I've tried each of the lines in the legend below.

```
 legend: {
       
      onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation()

      display: false 

      onclick(){}

    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are configuring it in the wrong place, you put it in `options.legend` while the legend options needs to be configured in the `options.plugins.legend` namespace